# Corresponding Webpack commands for each ng command in Angular8

Tags: angular, unit-testing, angular8, webpack-4, karma-webpack

For some reason the `ng build`, `ng test` and `ng lint` or I would say all ng commands are not allowed in our pipeline. So I am googling to know the corresponding `webpack` commands for each `ng` command in Angular8. Angular-cli 7 has the feature to do `ng eject` and get the `webpack.fonfig.js`. But that is also not supported in `angular/cli` version 8.

So my requirement is to configure angular8 project with webpack4 where I should be able to run build test and lint. I got few resources very closely but unfortunately I did't get test and lint.

https://github.com/samteb/angular-7-webpack-4-boilerplate (No test and lint command in package.json)
https://v2.angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/webpack.html (This is very old)

Please help me with any resource.

Comment: not clear whats your question but, the ng commands are in the package.json file and you can call them with npm run ...

Comment: I want to get exact command which ng build, ng test and ng lint does internally. If you do ng eject in angular 7. You will get `"start": "webpack-dev-server --port=4200",`. But how to achieve the same in Angular8.